Trying to install VSCode on Nvidia Jetson Nano
Returning with error:
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
        Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.17) but 1.16-2ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
        Depends: libxkbfile1 (>= 1:1.1.0) but 1:1.0.9-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have already tried apt --fix-broken install while in root. Also have tried downloading the flash version. All leads back to these dependencies that I can not fix.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

Does this answer your question? How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?

The oldest supported ubuntu version is 20.04, which has libc6 v2.31. You must be running an old and unsupported version of Ubuntu. Upgrade to/fresh install Ubuntu 24.04 to install VS Code and also to receive support on this site.

Thanks! Working on old system so didn't release how out of date it was.
